# Probability distribution of request handling

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, computer-science

I have values representing time taken to execute one request on server. Could somebody advise what type of distribution it is? I think that normal distribution but I am not really sure about it.

Thanks for your responses in advance.

**UPDATE**

Example situation: Consider you have collection of n values (from measurement process) representing time taken for i-th request to be executed on the server (i from 1 to n). What is the probability distribution of this time? (I know that it can be estimated applying input analysis methods, but in reality I don't have these values, I have only mean and deviation of them). In general, is it Gamma? Is it Normal? Or something else?

Comment: The distribution could be absolutely *anything* (with mass only in $[0, \infty)$). This needs to be specified as part of the problem.

Comment: Hows that possible? This is the real problem, so I thought that this information is generally known.

Comment: For example: suppose that the time taken to execute your request, $t(\ell)$, is a (deterministic) function of the server load. Then the distribution of your request's execution time will depend on the distribution of the server load...

Comment: Well, I don't mean only one request, I mean request execution in general. Can be this distribution defined?